# add annotation in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, beamerposter

I have this simple beamer code.

```
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> Step 1: class $<$ClassName$>$:  By convention the name of a class starts with a capital letter.
\item<2-> Step 2: create a special method called the {\bf constructor}.  This method initializes the properties of the specific instance of the object being created.
\begin{itemize}
```

My question: how to make the "By convention the name of a class starts with a capital letter" an annotation? Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean, an annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something that you will see and the audience won't, then use `\note{}`. This won't work with every pdf viewer. Please read chapters 19 and 22 of beamer manual. Btw, you should give a MWE with preamble

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{second mode text on second screen=left}%This option causes the second screen to show the second mode material
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item<1-> Step 1: class $<$ClassName$>$:  \note{By convention the name of a class starts with a capital letter}.
    \item<2-> Step 2: create a special method called the {\bf constructor}.  This method initializes the properties of the specific instance of the object being created.
\begin{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```